# List with private setter

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm trying to allow users of my class to be able to add to list, not set. Hence I would like to have a private set like so:

```
public class Model
{
    private IList<KeyValuePair<string, int>> pair;

    public Model()
    {
        pair = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    }

    public IList<KeyValuePair<string, int>> Pair 
    {
        get
        {
            return pair.Where(x => x.Value > 0
                                          && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Key)).ToList();
        }
        private set { pair = value; }
    }
```

However when I add to `Pair.Add()` it doesn't work.

I've tried this (which works) but then I need the "Where" clause in get{}. How would I do it?

```
public class Model
{
    public Model()
    {
        Pair = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    }
    public IList<KeyValuePair<string, int>> Pair { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: In C# 6, you don't need the private setter. You can still set in the constructor (and the constructor only). I would probably create a function instead of using a property, in this case.

Comment: So you want users to add any value, but when they query for values you want to be able to filter it, right?

Comment: Pair returns a new temporary list, which is a copy of another list. You add to that list. It has more items now! Hurrah! Then it's gone, like tears in rain. Time... to delete all that linq garbage in `Pair.get()`

Comment: can't use c# 6. 4.5.2

Comment: @Yacoub Massad - yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use this approach, you would probably want to implement a public `Add()` method within this class in order to add elements to the underlying private property :

```
public class Model
{
        // Other code omitted for brevity

        public bool Add(KeyValuePair<string,int>> item)
        {
             // Add your item to the underlying list
             pair.Add(item);
        }
}
```

Presumably, you were using the results from your `Model.Pair` and attempting to add to it, which won't work as expected (as `Model.Pair` would be just returning a copy of your list and not the actual list itself).

Answer (score 1):

I would probably solved it with a method

```
public class Model
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> pairs = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public void Add(string key, int value)
    {
        pairs[key] = value;
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetPairs()
    {
        return from pair in pairs
               where pair.Value > 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.Key) == false
               select pair;
    }
}
```